# Parsing a text file into List with minimal memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, csv, memory-management

I have a text file that has 1.000.000 lines like these:

```
texta   text1   text#
text%   text9   textx
text'   text^   text3
```

It is 19.000.000 bytes in size... around ~18.5 MB in Windows Explorer.

I need to manipulate this file "in memory" and do Linq Queries on it with minimal memory footprint.
This is one application I created for testing and after loading the ~18.5 MB file, it eats ~47MB of memory.
Here is the code commented:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class FileClass
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Current Memory Heap Size: ~91 KB
            List<FileClass> fileClass = new List<FileClass>(); 

            //Current Memory Heap Size: ~172 KB
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\somewhere\\My19000KBFile.txt"))
            {
                string[] linepart = line.Split('\t');
                fileClass.Add(new FileClass()
                {
                    Field1 = linepart[0],
                    Field2 = linepart[1],
                    Field3 = linepart[2]
                });
            }

            //After bringing file in memory
            //Current Memory Heap Size: ~47,000 KB
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how can I bring such file in memory, parse it into a `List<Class>` without taking so big memory footprint?

Comment: If you change FileClass members from string to byte[] you should save 20MB, but does it worth the inconvenience?

Comment: It would most probably help if you could tell us what you need to do with the list, maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be very hard to lower the memory pressure if you read the entire file in memory and process it afterwards.

First, at the time of your break point, if there hasn't been a garbage collecting from reading the file contents, there is at least 18.5 MB x 2 in memory. That is 37 MB already.

Second, a `string` in .NET has a little overhead, just like the classes you create. That means you will have some loss in memory here too.

Jon Skeet has written a [blog article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings/) about optimizing strings in memory in C#. It might be useful to you to understand how you lost some memory and how to optimize string operations.

Comment: That was a very good blog article. I will help me out on the decision.

Answer (score 2):

In your case there is no need to load the file, each row is long 19 bytes, so access it at runtime:

```
private FileClass GetFile(int row)
{
    using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) 
    {
    streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(row*19, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    string[] linepart = line.Split('\t');
    return new FileClass()
            {
                Field1 = linepart[0],
                Field2 = linepart[1],
                Field3 = linepart[2]
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to perform Linq queries in the whole content, so I think I need to load the file in oppose to work by row.

Answer (score 1):

This code will read a line from the file (note that we read a line at a time not read all lines) when you access an element from the IEnumerable and will garbage collect the memory for each nCleanUpEvery lines parsed from the file (thus minimizing the impact of string buffering).

Hope this helps

```
    public static IEnumerable<FileClass> GetFileClasses(string strFileName, int nCleanUpEvery = 1000)
    {
        using(var reader = File.OpenText(strFileName))
        {
            int nParsed = 1; // Counter used to garbage collect
            string strLine;
            while ((strLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  // Parse every line
            {
                string[] linepart = strLine.Split('\t');
                yield return new FileClass()
                {
                    Field1 = linepart[0],
                    Field2 = linepart[1],
                    Field3 = linepart[2]
                };

                // Increment the number of lines parsed and For each nCleanUpEvery lines we garbage collect
                if (++nParsed % nCleanUpEvery == 0) 
                {
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    nParsed = 1; // Reset the counter
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<FileClass> fileClass = GetFileClasses("c:\\somewhere\\My19000KBFile.txt") ; 

        }
    }
```